# Change the Page Title of the Archive Page for Portfolio Tags

Tags: custom-taxonomy, tags, archives, custom-post-type-archives

I want to change the title of the archive page to the name of the Tag itself. See screenshot.

[image: ARCHIVE - to be changed to TITLE OF THE TAG]

This is under the Portfolio Taxonomy. Please help.

Comment: You should add the code of the template, so that users can help to change the template tag for your requirements.

Comment: very little point of asking how to change your code without displaying it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve my question. by just adding this code to the title function of my theme. I didn't know it was not included that's why.

```
    } elseif (is_tax() ) {
        $title = single_term_title( '', false );
```